# What should I consider when I plan a meaningful monitoring for SNMP Switch (SG200-50)

Tags: networking, cisco, monitoring, switch, snmp

I am currently planning the monitoring of a switch and would like to consider beforehand what I need to be closely monitored in order to obtain errors and warnings are also useful.

I have a Cisco SG200-50 and activated with the current firmware also SNMP. With snmpwalk I can already read the properties are only so many that it is very confusing. It would be tedious to go through each leave and so to gather the information together. I would like the CPU load and the traffic as a graph yet also monitor errors and warnings for all ports can be output.

Now to my questions.

1. With what SNMP objects can I monitor the traffic
2. To what object I find Packet error or CRC Errors
3. How can I display the CPU load and see what process is responsible

This information I would like to represent as a graph, because someone has already practical examples or do I really need the search all together yourself?

Comment: Just use something like MRTG or Cacti, it will show you all relevant informations and more without too much hassle.

Comment: I try MRTG but only get the Traffic Graphs, I can import the Traffic Values into nagios but I must create a Command for each Port, Error Value, Traffic ... What I want to know is there are any best practice for Switch SG200 Monitoring to detect errors and warnings?